# Simulation case for Double machine learning in Partial linear model with lasso where number of covariates is large

Tags: machine-learning, simulation, lasso, high-dimensional

I want to conduct a simulation study on double machine learning in Partial linear regression setup as described in Chernozukov's paper for Double machine learning. I want to use lasso and want the number of covariates to be larger than the number of sample . Can you please give a scenario? I can't find any example related to this .